# Should a user be allowed to delete his own old revisions on his own post?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history

It happens sometimes that a user has to edit his post multiple times. Stack Overflow maintains all these edits (exception: edits done very quickly) separately. This is necessary for historical purposes may be.

But, in many cases, this may not be needed. It might be just a progressive edit (where additional information is ADDED) or a spelling correction or formatting adjusted, etc.

Consider the following example:

> Original Post (User1)
>
> Edit 1 (User1) ==> Code block added
>
> Edit 2 (User1) ==> Spelling corrected
>
> Edit 3 (User1) ==> Additional description added to answer a comment

In this sequence, "Edit 3" contains all that is necessary. All other edits are improvements. For historical purpose, "Original Post" should always stay. But, should there be a feature that allows user to delete Edits 1 and 2?

The only reason I can think of for asking this feature is garbage cleanup. Similar to garbage questions, answers, comments are disposed, why not revisions as well?

I remember I read somewhere on meta that there is auto-delete script of old revisions. The manual delete by self will just speed up the process I guess.

If no; are there any drawbacks of providing such feature?

Comment: Are there any benefits of providing such a feature?

Comment: @ivarni: As mentioned in question: - "The only reason I can think of for asking this feature is garbage cleanup."

Comment: @mega6382: This is NOT a feature request. This is just a discussion whether such feature is necessary. **You should delete your own edit. .) .)**

Comment: so...how is a record of edit history garbage? People can only see it if they go look for it

Comment: @SurajRao: Very few users at very few times view the old edits for very few reasons. Specially, if the user himself understand that his own old edits are useless, why should he keep those?

Comment: For cases like your previous comment  to Cerbrus:)...Its a record of what changes you made when so that one day you dont end up asking "how/why did xyz change get on my post"?

Comment: *"The only reason I can think of for asking this feature is garbage cleanup"*, I'll take that as a no then. That's not a benefit. If you have to think long and hard about wether there are any benefits to doing X there probably isn't any benefit to doing it. Bute let me rephrase: Does providing such a feature solve an existing problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean merging the history per user into one edit, if so, what would stop me changing a popular question/answer with profanity, leaving it for a few hours and then changing it back to normal as merging the history would hide this.

Comment: So users would be able to post an answer quickly to get the first answer, take their time editing into shape, delete the earlier revisions and no one would be able to see what they are doing outside of employees.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I disagree with the point that the revision history is garbage.

It is a record of all edits consequential and otherwise and done by whom (a number of minor edits can even be suggested or made by other privileged users). They are not directly visible to a user unlike questions/answers and are viewed only by people looking for it to see who and when the change occurred.

You don't want to end up in Meta asking "Why did this change happen in my post?" after previously cleaning up your edit history.

Comment: In what way the edit done by @mega6382 on my question useful?

Comment: The _edit_ may not be useful. The _revision history_ was to figure out who added the tag which is my point. You may have found it immediately but would be difficult to figure out some time in the future who edited after deleting history

Comment: I was looking at this through my view. My purpose was constructive. The drawbacks mentioned in answers and comments were beyond my imagination.

Comment: @AmitJoshi well that's how discussion happens here... no one can think of all perspectives.:)

Answer (score 18):

## Nope.

There's too much potential for abuse.

Users could completely wipe a question's history, if they decide they no longer want to have the question online. This would only add to the already large pile of stuff moderators will have to deal with.

Comment: Original post will always there....

Comment: Which means you'd have to "merge" revisions, which is quite a bit of logic for very little gain.

Comment: @AmitJoshi unless they edit it to a single sentence like "F*** Y'all" and then proceed to remove all the revisions. This kind of edit happens every day. With your proposition, the user would then have succeeded in defacing their post.

Comment: Here's the problem: The original and most recent versions are clean. One of the intermediate versions is abusive. 

If that intermediate version is deleted, moderators are unable to act.